# Arduino uploading issue: "avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file"

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am receiving an error uploading to my Arduino.  The full error reads:

`avrdude: no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config file
         Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again`

The problem is, as far as I can tell, I should not even be using the programmer.  I am uploading via USB.  I have tried both a SparkFun Redboard and an Arduino Uno.

I thought that the trouble may be the code or the equipment that I was using so I even tried to upload to the board with nothing connected as it states in the Ardunio help files.

I have even loaded the most basic example code that I have used before.  I am using the GUI so I do not know how to use the -c option.  I am at a loss as to what is wrong.

I have tried various options on setting the Programmer.  I would think 'Arduino as ISP' would be correct but I have tried may others.  I am fairly new to Arduino and may be missing something painfully obvious.

The only other option I can think of is to uninstall and reinstall the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem.  Errors from 1.6.9 down to 1.6.5.  I am using the Chinese clone device on El Capitan as well.

I tried the directions from pert at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=366573.90

The problem is caused by using Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.10 with Arduino IDE 1.6.6, they are incompatible. The options to fix this are:
Use Arduino IDE 1.6.7 or 1.6.8
Install Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.8(due to a bug you can't go back to using 1.6.9) by: `Tools > Board > Boards Manager... > Arduino AVR Boards(click on it) > Select version > 1.6.8 > Install`.
Install Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.9 and then reinstall Arduino IDE 1.6.6, this will get around the bug linked in option #2.

With option #2 or #3 you will continue to get updatable notifications about the more recent Arduino AVR Boards version so you might want to `File > Preferences > Check for updates on startup` (uncheck) to disable this notification.

At first I thought the instructions did not work, but as it turns out, it instead appears like some combination of changes bricked my Arduino Nano.  Luckily, I have another and that one will upload sketches successfully using IDE 1.6.9 and 1.6.8 boards although this results in:

> WARNINGS: Category '' in library {EEPROM,SPI,SoftwareSerial,Wire} because the old core being used.

Comment: I guess I can't say.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the IDE and the problem resolved.  I know that is not a fix, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with an Arduino Uno (Genuino) board and Arduino CC IDE 1.6.7. It had shown me some message that new boards are installable, so I had installed AVR boards 1.6.14 from the Boards Manager (not sure what it had before). Note that for the installation buttons to appear at the platforms manager you first have to click one of the offered items, plus apart from the All filter there's an Installable filter.

Selecting from there to install 1.6.7 again worked, then tried with 1.6.8 and kept on working. Didn't try any higher like 1.6.9, glad it works for now

Not at all intuitive - btw, the errors dialog in that IDE has a very bad color choice - very tiring to read text there, especially if there's lots of it (plus no color highlighting done there which would make long error text more readable)

Comment: I did end up doing a uninstall/reinstall and it worked from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Arduino IDE 1.6.8 and have the same problem.There is always new library update and the problem exists for board package Arduino AVR boards version 1.6.12 to 1.6.14. I have to downgrade the version 1.6.11 and it is fine now. I am using Redbearlab Blend Micro.

Tools>Board Manager>Arduino AVR boards>Select version (1.6.11) > Install